# How to align a specific element to the center in jetpack compose Row?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am looking to replicate the layout attached below using `Row` in jetpack compose. Intuitively I feel it should be very simple but I am not able to pull it off. As you can see in the image the text `Secret` should be in the horizontal center of the row and the search icon at the extreme right of the row.

I tried many variations of the following code (with `Modifier.weight`)

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.home_screen_title),
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        fontFamily = TitleFontFamily,
                        lineHeight = 24.sp,
                        letterSpacing = 0.5.sp,
                        color = OnPrimary
                    )
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.search),
                        contentDescription = stringResource(
                            id = R.string.secret_search_description
                        ),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(12.dp)
                    )
                }
```

I am not able to bring the Text to the horizontal center of the layout. This shouldn't be so hard. What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with `Box` that have `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center` and adding `.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)` modifier to the `Image` composable

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
               .fillMaxWidth(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
) {
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.home_screen_title),
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        fontFamily = TitleFontFamily,
        lineHeight = 24.sp,
        letterSpacing = 0.5.sp,
        color = OnPrimary
    )
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.search),
        contentDescription = stringResource(
            id = R.string.secret_search_description
        ),
         modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(12.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. So, it's not possible in Row layout?

Comment: The idea is to get the text in center of the whole width and that's a little hard with ```Row``` considering the other element will take space from said whole width.
You could still try with ```Row``` and put an empty ```Box``` with appropriate width and height on the other side of the Row and set ```horizontalArrangment = Arrangment.SpaceBetween``` but that's not ideal and most of the time wouldn't really put the text in the exact middle.